# Python decode and encode with utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode, encode, python-3.3

I am trying to encode and decode with utf-8. What is wierd is that I get an error trackback saying that I am using gbk.

```
oneword.decode("utf-8")]
```

below is the error trackback.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character '\u2769' in position 1: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Can anyone tell me what to do? I seems that the `decode` parameter does not have effect.

Comment: What is `oneword`? Please update your post with the result of `print(oneword)`.

Comment: Actually `repr(oneword)` might be more useful.  The `UnidoceEncodeError` makes it look like its trying to first encode `oneword` before decoding it, as if `oneword` is a `bytes` object.  I haven't seen this behaviour before in Python 3 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved.
Actually, I intended to output to a file instead of the console. In such situation, I have to explicitly indicate the decoding of the output target file. Instead of using `open` I used `codecs.open`.

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open(filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Thanks to [@Bakuriu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/510937/bakuriu) from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/31669959):

> If you are using Python 3 you no longer need to import the `codecs` module. Just pass the `encoding` parameter to the built-in `open` function.

Comment: In python3 there is **no** need to import the `codecs` module. Just pass the `encoding` parameter to the built-in `open` function. You can achieve the same behaviour in python2 using `io.open`.

Comment: Adding to @Bakuriu: The `codecs` module actually has several annoying bugs that will likely never be fixed, and performs worse than the `io` module components (`open` *is* `io.open` on Python 3); you basically never want to use `codecs.open` unless your code needs to run unmodified all the way back to Python 2.5 (as of 2.6, `io.open` exists).